# My Question Is input : String s=" learning java programming by self" and output is : "gninrael java gnimmargopr by fles ? plese help"

Tags: java, arrays, string, replace

The String contains Group of words.Write a program to print even words in reverse and odd words as same in the given sentence.

i tried with split(" ") but i am not getting to reverse the even words

input is : "am learning java with stackoverflow"

output : "ma learning avaj with wolfrevokcats"

**Code:**

```
class StringJumbling { 
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        String s="my name is baghyavathi"; 
        String arr[]=s.split(" "); 
        String reverse=""; 
        int sr=arr.length; 
        for(int srk=0;srk>=sr-1;srk++) { 
            if(sr % 2 == 0) { 
                reverse = reverse + " " + arr[sr];
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println(reverse); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add the code you have attempted so we can see what is going wrong with your code.

Comment: lass StringJumbling
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  String s="my name is baghyavathi";
  String arr[]=s.split(" ");
  String reverse="";
  int sr=arr.length;
  for(int srk=0;srk>=sr-1;srk++)
  {
   if(sr % 2 == 0)
   {
    reverse = reverse + " " + arr[sr];
   }
   
   
  }
  System.out.println(reverse);
 }
}

Comment: looking like a homework question, get after it!

Comment: Just a recommendation: Stop naming variables with short names. It is really hard to read code where the variable names are like `s`, `arr`, `sr`, `srk`. The variable `reverse` is named really well. :)

Comment: After reading through and understanding the approach a bit more, even `reverse` is kind of the wrong name. Nonetheless, your attempt does not include any code that reverses a string. Also, your existing code does not even loop properly because of this confusingly named `sr` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guidance.
Create a function that can reverse any string. This could be approached by converting string to char array and then you've to loop in reverse order.

For selecting even and odd words, again you tokenize using split and then you can select even and odd based on index.

Now, you can target one point at a time to solve this problem. 
I hope this helps. That's how you learn the hard way. 
Find a way to convert string to char array and that's the only difficult part I believe for you based on your question. Good luck.